# Generic Way to Implement EF6 Code First

Tags: c#-4.0, generics, entity-framework-6, .net-reflector

I'm Using EF6 Code First (Generic Repository Concepts)

Example Code TO Create Record :

Generic.cs:

```
public T Create<T>(T t) where T : class
    {
        T newEntry = this.dbContext.Set<T>().Add(t);
        this.SaveChanges();
        return newEntry;
    }
```

Actual Code :

```
 var customer = new Customer{
                      Name = "Adams",
                      Amount = 1000
                    };
```

CustomerId is AutoIdentity Column It will Generate Id automatically.

Customer table having One To Many RelationShip with Products(CustomerID FK in Products Table)

Now I'm adding New CustomerID in the List of Products

```
var productsList = new List<Product>
{
    new Product
       {
           ProdName = "crocin", 
           Date = DateTime.Parse("2003-09-01"),
           Customer.CustomerId = newCustomerId // 
       },
    new Product
       {
           ProdName = "crocin1", 
           Date = DateTime.Parse("2003-09-01"),
           Customer.CustomerId = newCustomerId  // 
       },
    new Product
       {
           ProdName = "crocin2", 
           Date = DateTime.Parse("2003-09-01"),
           Customer.CustomerId = newCustomerId  // 
       } 
};
```

Now I'm hitting database twice because First I'm getting CustomerId then I'm assigning New CustomerId to all the Selected Products.

Here is the code :

```
var newCustomer = Generic.Create<Customer>(customer);
```

Iterating the list of products and I'm assinging the newCustomerId into Products..

```
foreach(var product in productList)
{
  product.CustomerId = newCustomerId;

  Generic.Create<Product>(product); 
}
```

Is it possible to change this code to more Generic way of implementing  soemthing like this..

```
Create(T parentTable, List<T> childTableList)
{
    // First Inserting ParentTable

     db.SaveChanges();

    //Fetching ID

    // Inserting Into ChildTables..

    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Please suggest me to extend this code...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're missing the `Customer -> Products` association. Try to add a reference to `Products` from your `Customer` class:

```
public class Customer
{
    public Customer()
    {
        this.Products = new List<Product>();
    }

    // your key
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Amount { get; set; }

    // ... rest of your data

    // the new association
    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can add them both in one call:

```
var productsList = new List<Product>
{
    new Product
       {
           ProdName = "crocin", 
           Date = DateTime.Parse("2003-09-01"),
           Customer.CustomerId = newCustomerId // 
       },
    new Product
       {
           ProdName = "crocin1", 
           Date = DateTime.Parse("2003-09-01"),
           Customer.CustomerId = newCustomerId  // 
       },
    new Product
       {
           ProdName = "crocin2", 
           Date = DateTime.Parse("2003-09-01"),
           Customer.CustomerId = newCustomerId  // 
       } 
};

var newCustomer = new Customer();

foreach (var product in productsList)
    newCustomer.Products.Add(product);
```

Then adding them to the context:

```
var newCustomer = Generic.Create<Customer>(newCustomer);
```

Comment: Thanks haim770 to  reply.. My Code is working fine.. but i want everything to be in single method.. like this..Create(T parentTable, List<T> childTableList)
{
    // First Inserting ParentTable

     db.SaveChanges();

    //Fetching ID

    // Inserting Into ChildTables..

    db.SaveChanges();
}  is this possible ? more generic way of implementing..

Comment: Refactoring the repository the way you suggest defeats the non-generic purpose of the repository as it's specifically tied to the `Customer` needs. You need to better understand what the role of an Object-Relational-Mapper (ORM) is. It lets you work with `objects` rather than `tables`, and (judging by the problem you present) your `Customer` should definitely hold a reference to the associated `Product` collection.